# stop all threads in the application

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to stop all threads in my application for 5 seconds.
How can I do it (without running over all thread and `foreach` of them all "sleep") ?

Thanks.

Comment: Application.Exit(); will stop your app threads :)

Comment: @Cody: Replace "threads" with any subject you care to name and your statement may well still be true. People who already know the right way to do a thing don't ask questions about how to do it.

Comment: *All* the threads? Then what thread will be running to wake them up? Do you mean all the *other* threads? Can you clarify the question? And can you clarify why you're rejecting the obvious solution?

Comment: @Eric: You're right; that was admittedly a dumb comment. I wasn't able to express my confusion and consternation regarding the question as elegantly as your last comment.

Answer (score 3):

There is no api (no windows api actually, not just in .net) for suspending whole process. You will have to iterate over all threads and suspend all except current. Then sleep 5 seconds on current thread and resume others.